# After installing 16.04.1, no boot...Just fails at Grub with flashing cursor

Tags: boot, partitioning, 16.04

I have an HP Envy Laptop 17" with Core i7 4700MQ, 8 GB of RAM, 1 TB HDD, and Windows 10 (upgraded from Windows 8.1). After a recent update I could no longer boot into Windows 10 so I did what I normally do when I have trouble with Windows, I boot into Linux to see if I can fix the problem. I initially installed 9.04 but my wireless would not work and neither did the USB so I downloaded and installed 16.04.1.

There was very little free space on my HDD so I downsized the large Windows partition by 80 GB to accommodate the new Linux install. The new partition is sda10 and the swap is on sda8.

[image]

I also downloaded and installed grub repair and ran the tool but to no avail. It made no apparent difference to the start procedure.

Obviously GRUB is the issue. How can I get GRUB to recognize the OS is on sda10?

I have disabled secure boot and enabled legacy boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem through hours of problem-solving. After James' answer failed and no one else offered suggestions, I went back to troubleshooting my Windows install with the help of Ubuntu live on usb.

Here is a sample of all the steps I took:

1) Flashed the bios with the latest version (I drove to the local library in order to do so, also buying another usb stick)
2) Performed many extra steps in Windows command prompt, including several boot repair strategies
3) Performed a 3 1/2 hr hard drive check with UEFI diagnostics, all passed
4) Re-downloaded Windows 10 ISO because another friend feared my ISO might have been corrupted
5) Downloaded Windows 7 SP1 ISO...couldn't install to HDD even with driver

That last one gave me an important clue and led me to the eventual answer. The BIOS could not register the HDD. It wasn't seeing it and I checked system information through the boot screen and it wasn't there.

I went back to the command prompt and tried one last time through diskpart to solve the problem.

- Diskpart
- List disk
- Select disk
- Convert gpt

Actually my main hard drive was already configured as GPT as shown under list disk but I performed the step anyway and went ahead and reinstalled Windows 10. Voila. This completely solved the problem I spent over a week trying to fix.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems I see by your description is the enabling of legacy boot.  Boot to the install media with UEFI enabled.  The system will more readily recognize what you have from that mode.  It'll use the mode that you boot to.  Install Ubuntu from the UEFI session.

After the install you'll have a BIOS choice of booting Windows or Ubuntu.  If you boot Ubuntu you'll come to the GRUB menu.  From that menu you will have a chance of booting Windows or Ubuntu.

This will cure the problem you're describing of Grub recognizing where the OS is.

By the way, looking at your image, you have a swap partition of less than 200megs.  You might consider having a swap partition about 1 1/2 the size of the amount of ram you have.  If you have 8 gigs of ram you'd benefit in performance by having 12 gigs of ram.  The 200 megs is a teaser to the system.  You might even be better off not having a swap if you can only allocate 200 megs.

Comment: No dice. Reinstalled Ubuntu with secure boot, deleted two irrelevant Linux partitions, and restarted. Also performed a hard reset. Now installed on SBA7/8. Error received is "No boot device found" Please install OS on HDD or something to that effect. With legacy boot you get the same blinking cursor. Also, because of all this Linux work I am no longer able to access the Windows recovery environment which would allow me to downgrade to Windows 8.1. I'm completely stuck. I've now installed Ubuntu about 7 or 8 times and have been without a working system for about 5 days. Using the Live 16.04.